# How to extract certain number of row (randomly) by matching three conditions in R

Tags: r, database, for-loop, dplyr, match

I have a simple problems here.
I have two data frame like below.
First one is a characteristics table that describes each category has a certain number of counts. 
I have 7 factors in age, 2 factors in Sex, and 17 factors in Year.  So the total combination is 7 x 2 x 17 = 238. The **Count** column says there are certain amount of people belongs to the each categories.

```
Table 1 (Characteristics Table)

Age   Sex   Year   Count
20    F     2010   30
30    M     2011   20
30    F     2011   50
40    F     2011   30
40    F     2012   20
50    M     2014   40
60    F     2015   40
70    M     2016   50
80    M     2017   10
.     .     .      .
.     .     .      .
continues (total row 238)
```

And next table 2 is people ID table which looks like below.

```
Table 2 (All data)

ID    Age    Sex    Year
1     20     F      2010
2     20     F      2011
3     20     F      2012
4     40     F      2011
5     40     F      2011
6     40     F      2011
7     60     F      2015
8     60     F      2015
9     60     F      2015
10    60     F      2015
11    60     F      2015
12    60     F      2015
13    70     F      2015
.     .      .      .
.     .      .      .
continues (total row 30,000)
```

I want to randomly select the number of **Count** (from table1) that matches the Age, Sex and Year condition from table2.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We can `left_join` `table2` with `table1` based on `Age`, `Sex` and `Year`. Select `Count` rows in each combination of `Age`, `Sex` and `Year`. Use `replace = TRUE` if you have higher `Count` value than the number of rows.

```
library(dplyr)

table2 %>%
  left_join(table1, by = c('Age', 'Sex', 'Year')) %>%
  group_by(Age, Sex, Year) %>%
  sample_n(first(Count))
```